# Unable to uninstall package in anaconda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I currently have tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu installed in a pre-made conda environment. I want to remove tensorflow but whenever I use

```
conda remove --name carnd-term1 tensorflow
```

I get the following error message

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '
```

Why I can't remove the package?

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4880

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4860

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure whether you used `conda` to install tensorflow because the packages whatever you install using conda will be under `~/anaconda` so if you get the error then it means that it is installed in some other path so `print sys.path` from where you can know the paths that python looks for library and you can manually remove the packages by looking at those paths. As of my knowledge if you have used `conda` then the package should be under `~/anaconda` if you used `pip/pip3` the package will be under respective python directory.

Comment: "Are you sure whether you used conda to install ..." Thanks, that was it for me. Just removed via pip.